# How to get value out of an object into an independent variable

Tags: javascript

I need to get a certain value from a wix website code.
I need to extract a value of a purchase so that I can send it to Facebook Pixel for tracking.

The simplified code on the thank you page looks like this:

```
if (typeof(eCom) === 'object') {
     
   eCom.eComAppConfig('thankYouPageApplication', {"appData":{"orderData":{"totals":{"value":5.0}}}});

}
```

I need to reference the value (5.0) further in the code. Could someone please advise me on how to get this value into a separate variable?

Further down the code I need to reference it here:

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {currency: "CZK", value: >>HERE<< });
```

Spent 4 hours trying, will be glad for any help. Thanks

Comment: you can override *eCom* object somewhere before. Where is it created in your code?

Comment: I cant modify this code. It's a wix site... So I need to get it done using only Google Tag Manager

Comment: So you're saying that you can't edit the upper javascript block? You're trying to extract it from the script itself?

Comment: Yes, no chance of editing the upper code.

Comment: Do you have access to the `eCom` object in your code at all?

Comment: No, I simply have a site, that I cant edit in code at all. Only thing I can do is insert tags through google tag manager. Client has the site on wix, so thats why...